# Question related to green's theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, greens-theorem

I am a not experienced in linear algebra, and I am not really sure how to tackle this problem. Thanks in advanced.

Show that,

$$\nabla u \cdot \mathbf m=(\mathbf m \cdot \mathbf n)\nabla u \cdot\mathbf n + (\mathbf m \cdot \mathbf t)\nabla u \cdot \mathbf t$$

where,

$$\mathbf m=(An_{x} +Bn_{y})\mathbf i + (Bn_{y} +Cn_{y})\mathbf j$$

is the vector in the direction of the conormal to the
boundary.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: Noted. My apologies, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula for $\mathbf m$ is irrelevant. The fact that $\mathbf t,\mathbf n$ forms an orthonormal basis for $\Bbb R^2$ tells you that for any vector $\mathbf m$ we have
$$\mathbf m = (\mathbf m\cdot \mathbf t) \mathbf t + (\mathbf m\cdot\mathbf n)\mathbf n.$$
Now dot with $\nabla u$.